# How to create horizonatal animated pager indicator using view pager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2, viewpagerindicator

I want to create a horizontal pager indicator like this
[image: horizonatal indicator]

And also while looking in stackoverflow most of the answers are using compose, but since I haven't migrated my project to compose it is quite difficult to work on compose.

I tried [this](https://github.com/avianey/Android-ViewPagerIndicator), and was able to create a circle page indicator but I am stuck with the animation part of the page indicator

Answer (score 1):

See [this GitHub page](https://github.com/kenilt/LoopingViewPager) for the following style:

[image]

And [this GitHub page](https://github.com/huseyinozer/TooltipIndicator) for the following style:

[image]

And [this GitHub page](https://github.com/vinodpandey/dotsindicator) for the following style:

[image]

And [this GitHub page](https://github.com/tommybuonomo/dotsindicator) for the following style: (More stars, up to date)

[image]